# Print Binary Search Tree Inorder

Tags: c++, printing, traversal, inorder

### Desired behavior

Print each level of BST with an extra tab, like this:

```
        level1
               level2
level0
               level2
        level1
               level2
```

### Actual behavior

```
        level1
                     level2
level0
               level2
        level1
                     level2
```

Here is my current code, and I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong:

```
 void AVLTree::printHelp(Node * node)
    {
        if (node == 0) {
            return;
        }   
        printHelp(node->left);

        indent = "";
        for (size_t i = 1; i < calculateHeight(node); i++)
        {
            indent += "     ";
        }

        cout << '\n' << indent << node->value;
        printHelp(node->right);

    }
```

Comment: What are the values of all the variables?

Comment: indent is just an empty string that i used to keep adding spaces to in order to show the levels of the nodes

Comment: What are left, value, and node? Also, what does printHelp() do?

Comment: Could you also show what the code you posted is printing instead?

Comment: @RookieProgrammer That's actually not enough context to diagnose your problem. Post a [MCVE] in your question please.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems with your code:

1. To view the tree, you need to tilt you head left. Therefore, you should be recursively first print the *right* child, then the node, then the *left* child.
2. By recalculating the node height for the indentation, you are squaring the complexity of this operation.

Try something like this:

```
#include <string>

void AVLTree::printHelp(const Node *const node, size_t height)
{
    if (node == 0) {
        return;
    }   

    printHelp(node->right, height + 1);
    cout << string(height, ' ')  << node->value << endl;
    printHelp(node->left, height + 1);
}
```

Call this with

```
printHelp(root, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But the output is now shown as a bunch of boxes with question marks in them followed by the node value.

Comment: @RookieProgrammer True, I mixed up the order of the arguments to `string`. Try the corrected version.

Comment: It now shows 50 as the root node, then 30 on the next level , then 40 & 20, and then 45&10. I';m starting to doubt my insertion function.

Comment: Try to just print out the root and its two immediate children, without anything fancy. There's a chance you indeed built the tree wrong.

Comment: @RookieProgrammer That's why you should have posted a [MCVE] of your code in question in 1st place. As is your question simply is off-topic.